# Binding two events, control order of execution

Tags: jquery

I'm having an issue with two events that are bound to the same element. Basically, one event is bound to all checkboxes, and one event is bound to a *specific* checkbox (with #ID). They trigger at the same time, but I want the ID-specific event code to run first.

These two events trigger at exactly the same moment, but I want #valid_only's event to be executed *before* the Search button is clicked in the general checkbox event:

```
.on('change', '#search-form input:checkbox', function() {
    $('#reset').button('enable');

    $('#search').trigger('click');
}).on('change', '#valid_only', function() {
    $('input:hidden[name="valid"]').val($(this).is(':checked') ? true : '');
    $('input:hidden[name="total"]').val($(this).is(':checked') ? '' : true);

    if (!$('#stats td[data-tag="months_to_expiry"], #stats td[data-tag="expired"]').hasClass('current')) {
        $('#stats td[data-tag="valid"]').toggleClass('e', !$('#valid_only').is(':checked')).toggleClass('current',  $('#valid_only').is(':checked'));
        $('#stats td[data-tag="total"]').toggleClass('e',  $('#valid_only').is(':checked')).toggleClass('current', !$('#valid_only').is(':checked'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing happens "at the same time" in JavaScript - it's (mostly) single threaded.  The events will be triggered exactly in handler registration order.

Therefore you need to register `#valid_only` before `#search-form input:checkbox`.

You *may* need to call `event.stopPropagation()` in the more specific handler to ensure that the event doesn't bubble up into the more generic handler.

Comment: Thank you Alnitak. I changed the order of the `.on()` bindings and it worked out exactly the way I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on this. Enforce the order of execution in your code :

```
.on('change', '#search-form input:checkbox', function() {
    if ( $(this).id() === 'valid_only' ){
        updateVisibilityValid( $(this).is(':checked') );
    }

    $('#reset').button('enable');
    $('#search').trigger('click');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put second part to some function and after '#search-form input:checkbox' function finishes it's job, just call that function:

```
.on('change', '#search-form input:checkbox', function() {
    $('#reset').button('enable');

    $('#search').trigger('click');
    foo_function();
});

function foo_function(){/* second part of "on change" */}
```